# Macro excel Hyperlink backing to Index and skipping creating a index hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that redo the table of contents page generated by our BI tool.  The reason I do this is I rename and resort all tabs in the worksheet.  I have two issues I'm trying to solve:

**1. I'm trying to skip a hyperlink being generated for the first sheet

 2. I will like to add a hyperlink in location (I1) on every
    other sheet that creates a hyperlink back to the Table of
    contents.**

```
Sub listsheets()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Sheets("TOC").Select
Range("C6").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
For Each s In Sheets

ActiveCell.formula = "=Hyperlink(""i'" & s.Name & "'!A4"",""" & s.Name & """)"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
i = i + 1
Next s

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
Sub listsheets()

Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Sheets("TOC").Select
Range(Range("C6"), Range("C6").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
Range("C6").Select
For Each s In Sheets
If s.Name <> "TOC" Then
Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    s.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:=s.Name
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
End If
Next s

Set rng = Range("C6")

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    If Sheets(i).Name <> "TOC" Then

        Sheets(i).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(i).Range("I1"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "TOC!" & rng.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:="TOC"

        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I added the piece you gave me to the code and it works but my first problem still appears how do I skip creating a hyperlink tab in sheet "TOC" for sheet "TOC".  Look at the revised code.

Comment: Just made an edit to ignore `Sheets("TOC")`.  See if that works

Comment: Thanks for the help but the edit strips the first function which is on the current TOC sheet, to add hyperlinks for everyworksheet.  The first edit I put there we were close the only other thing I wanted to do was on Sheet TOC in the first part of the coee it kept creating a hyperlink for TOC I wanted to skip that

Comment: Sorry, just added it back in

Comment: Also is there a way to make the return to TOC dynamic?  Meaning lets say I'm on sheet 30 and I click return to TOC it will take me to Sheet TOC but the cell location of where I click the hyperlink?

Comment: Since all the links to return to "TOC" are in Cell I1, just change `"TOC!C6"` to `"TOC!I1"`

Comment: But the links are running consecutively for example, C6 down to C92.  So If I click the link in C50 when I click return to TOC can I go back to C50?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107368/discussion-between-theguythatdoesntknowmuch-and-user3666237).